# Parsing Xml with A tag that contains multiple attributes [Java,DOM]

Tags: java, xml, dom

I use DOM parser to mine the data.Problem is that i cannot manage to get the "url=" "length" and "type" tag that is  inside the "enclosure" tag

```
<item>
      <title>blah blah</title>
      <description>blah blah</description>
      <enclosure url="THEURL" length="LENGTH" type="TYPE" />
</item>
```

Here's the code that i use : Can anyone point me to the right direction?

```
for (int t = 0; t < nList.getLength(); t++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(t);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    System.out.println("title : "
                            + getTagValue("title", eElement));
                    System.out.println("description : "
                            + getTagValue("description", eElement));                        

                    for (int t2 = 0; t2 < nList2.getLength(); t2++) {                           
                    Node nNode2 = nList2.item(t2);                  
                    Element eElement2 = (Element) nNode2;
                    System.out.println("url: "
                            + getTagValue("url", eElement2));
                    }
                }
        }

private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

    return nValue.getNodeValue();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look up the `Element.getAttributes()` method to retrieve all the attributes as an array. The `Element.getAttributeNode(String name)` will give you a specific attribute.